# PDO Query not return rows

Tags: php, pdo, authorization

im try do a login. So, i need check the role user. I write this code:

```
// $userId have a valid id, this is checked
$userId = $rs[0]['idusuario'];
$adminRole = "ROLE_ADMIN";
$cocinaRole = "ROLE_COCINA";
$autorizacion = "SELECT p.nombre FROM perfiles p INNER JOIN usuarios_perfiles up ON (p.idPerfil = up.idPerfil) WHERE up.idUsuario = :Usuario AND p.nombre LIKE :Role)";

$isAdmin = $conn->prepare($autorizacion);
$isAdmin->bindParam(':Usuario', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$isAdmin->bindParam(':Role', $adminRole, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$isAdmin->execute();
die(var_dump($isAdmin->fetchAll()));
```

The vardump show:

> array (size=0)   empty

With examples values in PhpMyAdmin, the query works fine, but here, in te PHP code always return an empty array.

Any ideas ?.

Comment: Change the code, and the result is empty.

Comment: your error handling is wrong. check http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

Comment: `$isAdmin->bindParam(1, $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);` and `$isAdmin->bindParam(2, $adminRole, PDO::PARAM_STR);` not works. Empty array is returned

Answer (score 0):

I have an error in te query:

```
$autorizacion = "SELECT...WHERE up.idUsuario = :Usuario AND p.nombre LIKE :Role)";
```

I have an parenthesis at end, that it should not be there.
Thanks !.

Comment: you are also using LIKE where strict comparison have to be used